# To the fall of which towers does Isaiah 30:25 refer?

Tags: history

To what does "the towers fall" refer in this passage?

> KJV Isa 30:25 And there shall be upon every high mountain, and upon
>   every high hill, rivers and streams of waters in the day of the great
>   slaughter, **when the towers fall.**

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to begin with the meaning of some of the symbolic metaphors.

Isa. 2:11-18 in prophesy of Judah and Jerusalem's destruction,

> *"11 The haughty eyes of man have been humbled, And bowed down hath been the loftiness of men, And set on high hath Jehovah alone been in that day.*
>
> *12 For a day [is] to Jehovah of Hosts, For every proud and high one, And for every lifted up and low one,*
>
> *13 And for all cedars of Lebanon, The high and the exalted ones, And for all oaks of Bashan,*
>
> *14 And for all the high mountains, And for all the exalted heights,*
>
> *15 And for every high tower, And for every fenced wall,*
>
> *16 And for all ships of Tarshish, And for all desirable pictures.*
>
> *17 And bowed down hath been the haughtiness of man, And humbled the loftiness of men, And set on high hath Jehovah alone been in that day.*
>
> *18 And the idols -- they completely pass away."* (YLT)

The towers are symbolic of strong places and strong men.

Just as high mountains symbolize strong nations, or kingdoms (Job 9:5; Psa. 78:54; Isa. 11:9; Jer. 17:3; 21:23; 51:25; Dan. 2:35, 45; etc.).

Hills symbolized lesser nations, or kingdoms (Psa. 18:7; 68:16; 97:5; 104:32; Isa. 17:13; 40:12; 41:15; etc.).

The Lord's holy mountain is the Lord's kingdom (Isa. 56:7; 57:13; 65:11, 25; 66:20; Joel 3:17, etc.).

The towers that men built were fortifications, strong places where they felt safe.  Fenced places, high mountains and hills where men could see enemies from far off, where they could trust in their own strength, and rely upon their stone walls.  They put their trust in these strongholds and they forgot to rely upon God.

Isa. c. 30 opens with the pronouncement of woe upon Israel (*"the rebellious children"* of vs. 1) for relying upon the strength of Egypt to help them against the army of Sennacherib.  The Israelite were not trusting in God, but in the strength of a pagan nation, and were making a treaty with Pharaoh - *"that walk to go down into Egypt"*, vs. 2.

But, a Messianic prophesy is inserted at Isa. 30:18-26 where they weep no more, and He answers their cries; where He gives the bread of adversity and waters of affliction - Christ is our bread and our living water (John 4:10); where the teachers (the apostles & disciples teaching the gospel) will not be hidden away, but will be seen and heard; and will speak of "the way" (vs. 21) they are to walk.

Christ said, *"I am the way, the truth, and the life..."*  (John 14:6)

The day of slaughter was also the day in which God would bind up the breach of His people (Isa.30:25, 26), and that healing of their wound would be through Christ, the Messiah (Mal. 4:2).

So, the falling towers of the Messianic prophesy section in Isa. 30:25 would apply to the strongholds of the unbelieving Jews at the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70.

They could also be used to apply to the immediate prophesy of the destruction of Sennacherib's army of the Assyrians (vs. 31).

In either case, the falling down of mountains, and melting of hills, and falling towers in God's prophesies refer to the strongholds of men: kingdoms, nations, fortifications, stone walls, etc.  Whenever men rely upon their own strength instead of relying upon God, they are putting themselves in place of God, and forgetting that it is His power and His will which matters.

Comment: Wow Gina. I can only guess how many hours you put into Bible study. This is an inspired a answer. +1

Comment: 3-4 Hrs most mornings.  Because I had questions many years ago that were not being answered by teachers and preachers at church.  I determined to research them myself.  Pays off to do the study.

Comment: Yes it pays to study. You may have the motivational gift for teaching. Only that can explain your ability to delve deep on your own.

Comment: 3-4hrs in the mornings means you start quite early right? I have lots of questions myself and even though this site is really helpful, there are some questions that have not been answered here.

Comment: Yes, I'm up very early.  I think we will always have questions, because His word is so very complete and the duality of natural to spiritual is present in all of it.  We get a little here and there, and then another connection pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the major prophets touch on the destruction of Babylon the Great. These passages may also be referring to this same destruction. Especially when you take in the emphasis of the towers, the mountains and all the turning away from our Lord. .

Comment: Hi Gary, welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Could you elaborate upon your argument? A few scriptural passages would help make it stronger. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is a [little different](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. Thanks!